# Insert/Select Mysql Spatial columns with ObjectionJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, spatial, objection.js

I have a location table with a 'Point' type column in MySQL. I could define it using Knex and it worked correctly.

```
knex.schema.createTable('locations',function(table){
  table.increments('locid').primary();
  table.string('address').notNullable();
  table.string('nick_name');
  table.specificType('loc_gis','Point').nullable();
  table.enu('loc_type',['home','office','college','other']).notNullable();
  table.timestamps();
})
```

But I do not know how to select/insert GIS Spatial data using ObjectionJS. Do I have to use raw queries everytime or is there anyway to write a plugin for ObjectionJS to handle Spatial Columns.

Comment: So Select works and returns {x:12,y:34} for the particular column. But I still need to figure out how to insert.

Comment: Wierd why the x and y are there.. POINT in MySQL doesn't contain keys.

Comment: I think, the mysql2 connector for node converts it ( or maybe the knex library on top of mysql2 connector).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The following code in my ObjectionJS Model definition, fixed the issue.

```
$formatDatabaseJson(json) {
 // Remember to call the super class's implementation.
  if(json.locGis){
    json.locGis=knex.raw('point(?, ?)', 
      [json.locGis.x, json.locGis.y]);
  }
  json = super.$formatDatabaseJson(json);
  return json;
}
```